# Element API return a type of Category

Tags: entries, matrix, categories, plugin-elementapi

I'm just wondering when it comes to Element API is there a way of returning a type of Category.

I'm returning all the other information fine.

[image]

```
'fees.json' => [
    'elementType' => 'Entry',
        'criteria' => [
            'title' => craft()->request->getQuery('title'),
            'section' => 'fees',
        ],
        'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            foreach ($entry->fee as $block) {
                $matrixSections[] = [
                    'first' => $block->firstInstallment,
                    'second' => $block->secondInstallment,
                    'full' => $block->full,
                    'grant' => $block->feeCategory
                ];
            }
        return [
            'title' => $entry->title,
            'menu' => [
                'sections' => $matrixSections
            ]
        ];
    }
]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The Element API plugin returns JSON, so you'll need to be specific about what you want to return for your categories – i.e. you can't return a CategoryModel (or an array of CategoryModels) in full directly from a Categories field.

The easiest option is to use [`array_map()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) like this:

```
'first' => $block->firstInstallment,
'second' => $block->secondInstallment,
'full' => $block->full,
'grant' => array_map(function (CategoryModel $category) {
    return [
        'id' => $category->id,
        'title' => $category->title,
    ];
}, $block->categoriesField->find()),
```

Of course, if your individual category has a lot of fields, you can always create an external function in your `elementapi.php` file and use that for the `array_map` call, instead of inlining the function (the external function needs to live above the `return ['endpoints']...` part):

```
function getCategoryData(CategoryModel $category)
{
    return [
        'id' => $category->id,
        'title' => $category->title,
        ...
    ];
}

...

'grant' => array_map('getCategoryData', $block->categoriesField->find()),
```

Also, there's the `$category->getAttributes()` method which can be handy if you want to return all stock attributes (i.e. `id`, `dateUpdated` etc – pretty much everything sans the title, for some reason):

```
function getCategoryData(CategoryModel $category)
{
    return array_merge($category->getAttributes(), [
        'title' => $category->title,
        'someCustomField' => $category->someCustomField,
    ];
}
```

Comment: Hey Mats, declaring the $matrixSections outside of the loop didn't make a difference. The only one of those options that returned anything was the ids option. Any other idea on this? Appreciate the reply none the less.

Comment: You're positive that the `feeCategory` field for the block in question actually has enabled categories selected?

Comment: I've added image to post to show that feeCategory has been added to the block.

Comment: I had a case of stupid earlier – please see revised answer. I even tested it this time :)

Comment: No worries. Appreciate the time anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure the answer from Mats also works but I thought the cleaner way would be the following.

```
'fees.json' => [
        'elementType' => 'Entry',
            'criteria' => [
                'title' => craft()->request->getQuery('title'),
                'section' => 'fees',
            ],
            'transformer' => function(EntryModel $entry) {
            $matrixSections = [];
            foreach ($entry->fee as $block) {
            $items = [];

            foreach ($block->grantType as $itemEntry) {
                $items[] = [
                'title' => $itemEntry->title,
                ];
            }
            $matrixSections[] = [
                'first' => $block->firstInstallment,
                'second' => $block->secondInstallment,
                'full' => $block->full,

                'items' => $items,
            ];
            }
            return [
                'title' => $entry->title,
                'menu' => [
                    'sections' => $matrixSections,
                ]
            ];
        }
]
```